# wedge product is linearly dependent

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

Suppose $a,b,c$ are in $\Lambda^1 V$. Then I must show that they are linearly dependent iff $a \wedge b \wedge c=0$.

I am new to tensors and wedges and I don't know how to proceed. I could only notice $\Lambda^1 V$ is the dual space $V^*$ so I can treat a,b,c as maps.

Let $a,b,c$ be linearly dependent. Then write $c=ka+rb$.
Then $a\wedge b \wedge c(x_1,x_2,x_3)=3! Alt(a \otimes b \otimes c)(x_1,x_2,x_3)=3! \sum_{\sigma \in S_3}a(x_1)b(x_2)(ka+rb)(x_3)= 3! \sum_{\sigma \in S_3}ka(x_1)b(x_2)(a(x_3))+3! \sum_{\sigma \in S_3}ra(x_1)b(x_2)b(x_3) $
I don't seem to be making any progress after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the basic properties of the wedge product? In particular that it is multilinear? So if $c= ka + rb$ then $a\wedge b \wedge c = a\wedge b \wedge(ka+rb) = ka\wedge b\wedge a + r a\wedge b\wedge b=0 $ since $a\wedge b = - b\wedge a$, so whenever $ a$ or $b$ 'occurs' twice in a product that product will vanish.

Comment: What about the other direction?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I was under the impression the OP was stuck at a certain point and wanted help with that, so I restricted my answer to that issue.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for the hint. Is there a trick to other direction?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, could you please help me with the other direction? I think I am stuck on that.

Comment: @user96343 the best approach to the other direction depends on the definition and the calculation rules for $\wedge$ you have learned. What will always work is to extend $a, b, c$ to a basis $a=v_1, b=v_2, c= v_3, v_4 \cdots, v_n$ of $\Lambda^1 V$ and choose a dual basis $w_i$ of $V$, i.e. $v_i(w_j) =\delta_{ij}$. Then you can either calculate $v_1\wedge v_2 \wedge v_3 (w_1, w_2, w_3) \ne 0$ or $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n(w_1,\cdots w_n) \ne 0 $ which implies no sub product can be $=0$.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks.